# Angular 4 Material 2 - How to change tabbing from being vertical to horizontal with MD-Gridlist?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

I'm currently attempting to switch the tabbing inside of an MD-Gridlist to tab hoizontally rather than vertically. I have tried using tab indexes and had no luck. I want to be able to tab through this dynamically growing or shrinking grid list horizontally.

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fieldsTable; let i = index">
                <!--condition in the grid-list tag checks if the key filed can be shown -->
                <md-grid-list class="static-column" cols="1" rowHeight="25px" *ngIf="field.$type == GlobalVariables.typeClasses.Static && (field.Name !== '' || showKey)">
                    <md-grid-tile class="field-name-tile theme-primary" *ngIf="!field.IsKey;">
                        {{field.Name}}
                    </md-grid-tile>
                    <md-grid-tile class="field-name-tile theme-primary" *ngIf="field.IsKey && showKey" mdTooltip="Key field used to update data for this row via the api, values must be unique.">
                        <md-icon>vpn_key</md-icon>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                    <md-grid-tile class="static-field-tile theme-accent-alternating " *ngFor="let content of field.ContentData; let i = index">
                        <md-input-container class="content-data-input">
                            <input class="field-input" mdInput (keyup)="content.Value=$event.target.value" value="{{content.Value}}">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                </md-grid-list>
            </ng-container>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I've hit a roadblock.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show a plunker? The default behavior is to tab in the order of the dom. [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MhHY870n2gFzCw99pGWj?p=preview)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/91af227e8b5baace1afa311fb959352a

This is a screenshot of the card it's encased in. I numbered how I'm attempting to get the table to tab. 

Also i don't know how to use plunker.

Comment: The grid list can have an arbitrary number of rows and columns in this case.

Comment: So in your screenshot, you have 5 vertical grid lists, is that right? If so, I would suggest making your grid lists horizontal (Row1 is a single grid list) so that your markup matches your expected tab behavior. I would even more strongly suggest using md-table instead of grid lists for this

Comment: Well i don't want to switch this specific bit to an Md-Table, also preferably i'd like to just be able to just change the tabIndex with the formula (innerIndex * outerArrayLength) + (outerArrayIndex + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remedy this by:

Adding this to the input container html  which live in the grid tiles of the grid list

```
tabindex={{setTabIndex(i,j)}}
```

and this in the TypeScript

```
setTabIndex(outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number): number {
    return (outerIndex + 1) + (innerIndex * this.staticTableLength);
}
```